# Set Google API key restriction on referrer - avoid localhost abuse

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-data-api

I have a google API account and would like to restrict its (ab)use by using the choice offered by google to restrict access to certain referrers.

Today I have set a restriction on

```
localhost
*.mywebsite.com/*
```

And all works smoothly.

But I am wondering: there is in anyway a secret key and nobody without this secret key can access our Google Data API quota.
But as google writes on the Security page "Restrictions prevent unauthorized use and quota theft."
So I guess it's a extra layer of security: if someone was to steal/find our secret key, then he would still be blocked by this second layer of security as only websites authorized can access our quota.

But then my question is: nobody can make requests coming from *.mywebsite.com/* as we own this domain, but what about localhost ? I mean we need it (a lot!) to make our requests when developing locally but I guess anybody who would steal/find our secret key could add 'localhost' too and make requests form his localhost server, thus putting our quota to zero. 
so the whole point of the url referrer to avoid abuse for people having the key is "defeated" if you add localhost...

Am I missing something here ? should we remove localhost as a URL referrer restriction as a bad security practice ?

Comment: How about creating a different secret key for local tests?

Comment: It's not a "secret key" if you are using it for the Google Maps Javascript API v3, it **has** to be public.  Best to create a different key to use for localhost.  There are ways to load different keys for different environments, so it doesn't have to be painful.

Comment: @geocodezip We are using it to retrieve data in our back office. The "public"/external audience sees the final data and never loads a page sending a request to google maps. Only our staff can access the backoffice which will send google a request.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour true I could. I was wondering if there was a better way , in order not to multiply the keys, which is also a way to reduce/dilute security when you have too many:)

Comment: Is `localhost` even working for restricting access to a key from your local host computer? I don't think that has any effect. Another way to restrict access to your keys, obviously, is to use an IP address.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the use of an external service and not about programming.

Comment: @MrUpsidown yes localhost can be used and it works (multiple questions on SO about using localhost for google api security) .

Comment: @MrUpsidown i'd love to be able to use "restriction by ip ". I was using it actually before moving to "restriction by référrer " . But i can't: Google offers an exclusive choice :it' s either refferer or ip, you can't use both. So if you use ip, it definitely solves the issue when we work locally but not in production :we ´ re hosted on heroku and our heroku servers don't have a static ip :( (that' s how heroku works). The only solution would be over -engeneered with a proxy setting a static ip for all our outbound traffic. So we prefer using referrer.

Comment: Mhhh... are you sure it's an exclusive choice? I believe you can use IP addresses in "HTTP Referrers" and therefore have a mix of domain names and IP addresses.

Comment: mmm..that would work! I did not know, let me try later today. thanks for the help.

Comment: @MrUpsidown thnaks it works. I took the choice ip/server too "literraly"/stricly.